# Two Domains. One Repo. Need Second License

Tags: license

I have two different domains that are both being deployed from the same Github repo. Domain A has a Craft license. Domain B needs a Craft license. I don’t want to transfer from Domain A to Domain B but they are both reading from the same `craft/config/license.key` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH](https://craftcms.com/docs/php-constants#craft-config-path) PHP constant on a per site basis so each of the sites will get their own `craft/config` folder (and therefore their own `license.key` files).

Comment: Update for Craft 3: There's now a dedicated PHP constant you can set for this: [CRAFT_LICENSE_KEY_PATH](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/php-constants.html#craft-license-key-path)